# Although vs Though?

Tags: grammar

Are these acceptable usages:

> **Though** it was raining, we had a good time.
>
> **Although** he didn't know the man, it didn't really matter.
>
> It could be anyone next **although** the alternative wasn't much better.

Comment: As conjunctions, although and though are interchangeable. Although is generally considered more formal than though, though both forms appear regularly in both formal and informal writing. 

Though is also an adverb meaning however or nevertheless. In this sense, though is not interchangeable with although, which is only a conjunction. http://grammarist.com/usage/although-though/

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, 'although' and 'though' are interchangeable in your example sentences.

> Though it was raining, we had a good time. 
> = Although it was raining, we
> had a good time.
>
> Although he didn't know the man, it didn't really matter.  
> = Though he didn't know the man, it didn't really matter.

When 'though' is tacked onto the end, just use 'though':

> It was raining. We had a good time, **though**. 
> He didn't know the man. It didn't really matter, **though**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all of them.  Though and although are pretty much interchangable.